# Android Application and Web Interface for the same

Tags: website, android, hosting, web-application

I have to develop an android application for my project. Also, i have to develop a web interface for the same. My present idea is to host the application at the google apps. I will be building the application on the java and will be using a sql-lite database.

For the web interface, i will be hosting the code in the same app. The code will be in php with jsp somewhere for the algorithms that are primarily in java.

Am I thinking right, or is there some easy way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps only supports Java and Python for server-side languages, BigTable for your database.

Without knowing more about your application, I can tell you: the simplest way to go about this is to not get stuck up on technology. Go with what you know, otherwise it will never get done. Also, an Android app can be as simple as serving as the "chrome" to your website. Your site itself can determine how it will present itself to the user based on the user-agent requesting it.